# Posting links are merging

Tags: facebook, hyperlink, facebook-wall

I am developing a facebook application and a big part of it involves posting links to a user wall. However, most of the links posted are of the same page, with the HTML parameters being the only difference between them.

Facebook usually sees that this user has posted many times the same link (even though by the parameters, the outcome is different) and merges them in a single wall post. Well, not exactly in a single wall post, but rather hides all old links and keeps only the newest one, while pointing all the posts made to the same link.

Is there a way to make facebook stop stacking these posts so they'll appear individually in the friend's newsfeed?

Answer (score 1):

Facebook looks at the value of the `og:url` tag as the canonical url for the page. If you want to use query parameters to show different content, you need to have a server-side script that echoes these in the `og:url` tag.

Comment: I see... Does the og:url necessarly need to follow an existing URL or is that optional? I could make it go to a fictional URL composed of the parameters so it wouldn't gather the posts.

Thanks for the help

Comment: The url in the `og:url` tag will be the source for the open-graph metadata that displays on Facebook, so no, you can't use a fictional url. The Facebook parser will visit this url.